# Accidental C Fork Bomb - Keeps forking after being killed

Tags: centos, c, fork

I am in charge of a CentOS 7 server running kernel 2.6.32 which is used for people to learn the basics of C under Linux, which unfortunately includes `fork()`. Sometimes honest accidents happen, where a process keeps forking over and over, behaving like a fork bomb.

First time this happens, I usually kill the base process which shows in `htop` and `ps aux`, but the problem doesn't seem to be gone. According to `htop`, `/sbin/init` is using all CPU power, across 8 cores, but it only shows about 14% usage, instead of the expected 800%. No other process shows as using resources.

I have checked various tools to help debug this, such as `execsnoop` which unfortunately doesn't show anything except for tons of:

```
31252     68 /usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 11 0 31248 48676 600 1620889853 e
31262     68 /usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 11 0 31258 48676 600 1620889853 e
31266     68 /usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 11 0 31261 48676 600 1620889853 e
31281     68 /usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 11 0 31278 48676 600 1620889853 e
31300     68 /usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 11 0 31296 48676 600 1620889853 e
31303     68 /usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 11 0 31299 48676 600 1620889853 e
31319     68 /usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 11 0 31315 48676 600 1620889853 e
```

Another one was `forkstat -X`, which shows the process in cause forking and exiting (always one "Exit" less than how many "Fork"s), along with many other instances of the above processes:

```
10:33:54 exit  14372 ncig041 ncig041      ? ⇥    11   0.003s ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 exit  14373 rmar201 rmar201      ? ⇥   256   0.004s ./a.out aeiTou
Time     Event   PID     UID    EUID TTY     Info   Duration Process
10:33:54 fork  14374 ncig041 ncig041      ? ┬parent          ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 fork  14376 ncig041 ncig041      ? └child           ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 exit  14374 ncig041 ncig041      ? ⇥    11   0.004s ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 exit  14371 rmar201 rmar201      ? ⇥   256   0.007s ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork  14375 rmar201 rmar201      ? ┬parent          ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork  14377 rmar201 rmar201      ? └child           ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork      1    root    root      ? ┬parent          /sbin/init
10:33:54 fork  14378 ncig041 ncig041      ? └child           ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 exit  14376 ncig041 ncig041      ? ⇥    11   0.003s ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 fork  14377 rmar201 rmar201      ? ┬parent          ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork  14379 rmar201 rmar201      ? └child           ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork  14378 ncig041 ncig041      ? ┬parent          ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 fork  14380 ncig041 ncig041      ? └child           ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 exit  14378 ncig041 ncig041      ? ⇥    11   0.002s ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 fork  14379 rmar201 rmar201      ? ┬parent          ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork  14381 rmar201 rmar201      ? └child           ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 exit  14377 rmar201 rmar201      ? ⇥   256   0.003s ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork  14381 rmar201 rmar201      ? ┬parent          ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork  14382 rmar201 rmar201      ? └child           ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 exit  14379 rmar201 rmar201      ? ⇥   256   0.003s ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 exit  14375 rmar201 rmar201      ? ⇥   256   0.011s ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork  14380 ncig041 ncig041      ? ┬parent          ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 fork  14383 ncig041 ncig041      ? └child           ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 fork  14382 rmar201 rmar201      ? ┬parent          ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork  14384 rmar201 rmar201      ? └child           ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 exit  14380 ncig041 ncig041      ? ⇥    11   0.005s ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 exit  14381 rmar201 rmar201      ? ⇥   256   0.004s ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 exit  14382 rmar201 rmar201      ? ⇥   256   0.004s ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork  14384 rmar201 rmar201      ? ┬parent          ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork  14385 rmar201 rmar201      ? └child           ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork  14383 ncig041 ncig041      ? ┬parent          ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 fork  14386 ncig041 ncig041      ? └child           ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 exit  14383 ncig041 ncig041      ? ⇥    11   0.003s ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 exit  14384 rmar201 rmar201      ? ⇥   256   0.003s ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork  14385 rmar201 rmar201      ? ┬parent          ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork  14387 rmar201 rmar201      ? └child           ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork  14386 ncig041 ncig041      ? ┬parent          ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 fork  14388 ncig041 ncig041      ? └child           ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 exit  14386 ncig041 ncig041      ? ⇥    11   0.002s ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 fork  14387 rmar201 rmar201      ? ┬parent          ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork  14389 rmar201 rmar201      ? └child           ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 exit  14345 ncig041 ncig041      ? ⇥   139   0.044s ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 exit  14351    root    root      ? ⇥     0   0.041s [/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp 11 0 14345 48676 600 1620891234 e]
10:33:54 fork  14389 rmar201 rmar201      ? ┬parent          ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork  14390 rmar201 rmar201      ? └child           ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork  14388 ncig041 ncig041      ? ┬parent          ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 fork  14391 ncig041 ncig041      ? └child           ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
10:33:54 exit  14387 rmar201 rmar201      ? ⇥   256   0.004s ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 exit  14385 rmar201 rmar201      ? ⇥   256   0.006s ./a.out aeiTou
10:33:54 fork  14390 rmar201 rmar201      ? ┬parent          ./a.out aeiTou
```

And a summary of:

```
Fork     Exec     Exit Coredump     Comm    Clone   Ptrace      Uid      Sid    Total Process
 729        0      728        0        0        0        0        0        0     1457 ./a.out aeiTou
 457        0      454        0        0        0        0        0        0      911 ./712_2_Laborator9_9 1 2 3 4
 131       43        0        0        0        0        0        0        0      174 khelper
   0       62        0        0        0        0        0        0        0       62 abrt-hook-ccpp
   9        0       18        0        0        0        0        0        0       27 <unknown>
  (many instances of abrt-hook-ccpp)
```

Another thing I tried was to set up the following, executed with niceness 20, but `forkstat` says it's still going.

```
while [ 1 ]; do killall -STOP -u userrunningthebomb ; done
```

I have also tried setting the `ulimit` and `/etc/security/limits.conf` for the offending user, but it did not solve the problem. The server should not be rebooted.
The process in cause does not show up anymore anywhere, neither in `ps aux` nor in `htop`.

> NOTE: a.out and 712_2_Laborator9_9 are two separate processes that both exhibit the same behavior. The one described here is 712_2_Laborator9_9, as it's pretty much the same thing for a.out

Except for a reboot, I don't know what else I could do. This is not the first time it happens, and I would like to learn about why this happens and how to solve the problem. Many thanks!

Here is the problematic source code. Note that it might've changed by the time I found it, but it shouldn't be too far off.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
//this will be the values array containing the transitted param as int 
int values[argc-1];
int i = 0;

//in the values array are memorized the ints from param        
for( i = 1; i < argc ; i++){
    values[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]);
}

    
// n resembles the nr of integeres passed
int n = argc - 1;
i = 0;

//the arrays answer
int answers[n];
int sum = 0;

//process forking
int process;
//process = fork();

//sum + print
for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
    process = fork();
if(process == 0){
    int j = 0;
    for(j = 0 ; j <= i ; j++){
    //printf("%d\n", values[j]);
    sum = sum + values[j];
    }
        printf("Process%d: %d\n", i, sum);
    exit(0);
}
wait(0);
    
}  
}
```

Comment: Managed a student VM in the past, and professors had sudo root for helping students. Was limiting each user like to 2000 files/200 processes/2GB disk quota, and on top of it an active watchdog that rebooted the machine if someone managed to stall it. When a student exhausted their  allotted 200 processes, a professor had to step in to kill them all.  It worked pretty well.

Comment: That would be a nice solution in the future, although in this scenario it looks like there's at most one process at a time. Will keep this in mind!

Comment: Unless my C is way more rusty than I think, the given source code isn't a fork bomb. The child processes all exit without proceeding further into the loop and forking.

Comment: It seemed strange to me too, but this is the source that is causing one of the issues, so it's probably not a fork bomb, but probably abuses the fork, as forkstat suggests. Maybe the source has been changed since the program was launched. I'll mention this